# VSTO Addin does not load when Document created from Template and VSTO Customization Error, WHY?

Tags: deployment, vsto, add-in, manifest, office-2007

i have created a VSTO addin in VS 2008 for Office 2007. it loads perfectly when Word is started as a standalone.

i have another application that starts a Word document, using a template and fills up the required details in the template.

The problem is that when Word is started from this application, the addin is not loaded,
and the Event viewer shows an error :

Customization URI: file:///C:/Program Files/S2B/S2B Office 2007 Addin/S2B.Word2007.vsto
Exception: The deployment manifest could not be downloaded because a connection to the network could not be established. Ensure that you can connect to the network, and try again.

the addin files(*.vsto), the manifest files(S2B.Word2007.dll.manifest) and other dlls required for the addin are stored in the "C:/Program Files/S2B/S2B Office 2007 Addin/" folder and there is no network involved in the entire operation.
the addin is independent of the application.

If i start Word standalone, the addin is loaded and if i them create the Template document from the application, then the Addin is loaded and i can use its 
functionality, there is no problem here.

Why this strange behavior AND how do is solve the error ??

Answer (score 0):

Haven't tried that particular combination myself, but it almost sounds like an issue with how you're starting Word from the "other" app.
Have you tried starting word, just bare, from the other app, using, say CreateObject, and the automating the load of the template and subsequent new doc? I wouldn't think it'd make a difference, but....

Finally, when you say "i have another application that starts a Word document, using a template and fills up the required details in the template"

Exactly how is the other application starting word? that might provide some clues.